# Everything looks fine in edit mode, but distorted in object mode

Tags: animation, armature, bones, object-mode, distort

Disabling modifier in viewport does the thing, but I want to animate it, which isn't possible with the armature disabled (see [this clip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OAA_ohl_VhQC_vtTgsmZ0hKIWXuXuH7l)).

I look to some posts with the same issue:

- https://blenderartists.org/t/model-looks-different-in-edit-mode-than-in-object-mode/561625
- https://blenderartists.org/t/looks-fine-in-edit-mode-distorted-in-object-mode/577266

  ...and tried this:

  - *Select Armature > Pose Mode > Pose > Clear Transform > Location (alt G), Rotation (alt R), Scale (alt S)* (nothing's working).

Download the file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DYYQXdclV-7IkPnLh4qyZN1T2Gwujoni).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the .blend file and can't reproduce the issue. Maybe disable some addons, get a clean install of Blender, etc. Here's what I did right after opening the file, everything seems fine to me, let me know if I missed something: 
[image]